# calculating the sentiment score of a sentence using ngrams

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I've a question that relates to the sentiment analysis of each tweet or for that matter any sentence in use.

Let's take an example: "This is no fun"

Now I've a unigram and a bigram.

Unigram
no: -3
fun : 4

Bigram
no fun: -3

My question is when I search for the words from the unigram and bigram in the sentence, which one should give preference to? Ideally the bigram. Right?

Taking a longer sentence, how should my program be written so that if a combination of words in the unigram makes a bigram word, the bigram should be given preference and the sentiment score of the unigram should not be included.

Any ideas?

Comment: Solved. First perform the sentiment analysis on the bigram. Then remove the words from the sentence that have already been counted. Now perform the sentiment analysis using unigram.

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe, in your comment on your question, works:

1. Perform analysis with bigrams
2. Remove any words that matched
3. Perform analysis with unigrams

But it requires modifying the source, and doing two passes, both of which are slow (for why, see the Update below).

An alternative is to take your bigrams scores and subtract the unigram scores of the words in them. You do this as a pre-process step, when loading the bigrams into memory. So your -3 "no fun" score would be modified with - -3 (+3) for the "no" and -4 for the "fun", leaving a net score of -4.

Now you can do a single pass, analyzing both unigrams and bigrams in that same pass.

On the sentence "This is no fun":

- This: 0
- This-is: 0
- is: 0
- is-no: 0
- no: -3
- no-fun: -4
- fun: +4

Giving a grand total of -3, which is the same as with your approach.

This scales to using n-grams.

(I've no idea if I read about this algorithm, or worked it out for myself, so I cannot tell you the official name for it.)

**UPDATE:**

The above is just an optimization of the "bigrams, delete_them, unigrams" process. It always gives exactly the same results.

The modification step I mentioned is to pre-process the bigram scores, from their real values to ones that allow you to do everything in a single pass. (This is done once, then the modified values are cached, and only need to be recalculated when add/remove words from the dictionary, or change any of the sentiment values: this is usually much less frequent than using the sentiment values to analyze text.)

Taking the longer example from your comment:

> "This game is no fun this time. Last time was actually more fun. No?"

On the combined pass approach, the values to sum are:

- no_fun x1 = -4
- no x2 = -6
- fun x2 = +8

For a total of -2. If you do it as the three-step process, the bigram pass gives you -3. Then you remove the bigram match(es) to get:

> "This game is **_** this time. Last time was actually more fun. No?"

The unigram pass finds one "fun" (+4) and one "no" (-3), so the net total from the unigram pass is +1. Adding that to the -3 from the bigram pass gives you -2. I.e. the same result, but more work.

**Why Const Is Faster**

Many compilers can do additional optimizations of code if they know a memory block will not change. But, more importantly it means multiple threads can safely operate on the memory block, without needing to lock their access.

In addition, in this case, if you are going to modify the input string, you will most likely make a copy of it, because you are going to want to keep the original (e.g. for reporting back the sentiment to the user, or for later processing steps). So, by promising not to modify the input string, you can use it directly, and save a copy.

**Why A Single Pass Is Faster**

You could argue that it will take the same number of CPU cycles to analyze unigrams, followed by bigrams, as to analyze both on the same pass. And that is reasonable. But a single-pass is quicker because of CPU cache: the memory only needs to be fetched into L1 cache once to analyze all your n-grams if you have a one-pass algorithm. It needs to be fetched in twice if you have a two-pass algorithm.

What about if you are using constant memory, and realize you could have bigrams in one thread, and unigrams in another thread? Assuming the two threads run on different cores, and assuming they don't run at exactly the same speed, they will end up fighting over the cache, and keep replacing the other's cache entries. It will still finish quicker than using one thread to do one pass, but it won't be twice as quick.

Comment: Hi Darrek, That makes sense when the number of words in my dictionary is really less. If we take an example "This game is no fun this time. Last time was actually more fun. No?" Here I don't want to subtract the monogram score of word "fun", which actually is a +ve sentiment. This would require again look if the monogram has already been counted in the bigram and then not counting the score. Hope you get what I'm trying to say.

Actually I am using regex to delete the two word bigram from the sentence. And ob. regex will be slow with longer sentences.

Comment: @nEO I expanded my answer. I hope it is clearer now.